# whats the minimum number of time periods needed to get a rewasonable statistical power

Tags: time-series, statistical-power

I'm running multiple regression analysis with 3-7 indep. variables using macroeconomic indicator data from the World Bank. MOST of the World Bank data sets begin no earlier than 1990, which means my time series are at best 1990-2012=22 "observations".
I understand measuring statistical power and have seen power tables for multiple regression, correlation, etc.
a. do I just pretend my time series is like any other multiple regression when applying power analysis?[i.e. n=22]
b. is a time series of only 22 "observation" periods automatically bad[I've seen repeated references to needing 30+ being the preferable number of periods; any source to explain this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the size of the effect, and the amount of noise confounding your estimate.

One common way to improve power in time series is by using multiple counties and making a panel data set. However, this approach may not be applicable with your intended research goals.